# in XCode 12.2 how to increase the font size of the whole UI

Tags: xcode, themes

Ignorant ways of XCode and its creators again come into place! :) Do you know how to change all fonts so text is larger? I managed only to increase text size in the left files menu, and the source code editor menu (source code text size can be done via Themes). How to change these other fonts here. Please see on the image. The green circles are how I would like all text size to be. The red ones, I really would like increased.

[image]

Comment: I think the only solution would be to change the definition of you screen because Xcode (as most of the macOS apps) doesn't allow resizing its labels. On the other side, codes can be set exactly as you want, not only by changing the theme but also by editing a theme or creating a new one.